# How to rotate scrollView with subView on it

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a problem on rotation. I have a scrollView which contains 52 imageViews. Suppose 12 imageViews （4 rows with 3 imageViews each row） when it is portrait. Now, I want to rotate the device and the result I want to get is that:  the same 12 imageViews (3 rows with 4 imageViews each row) will be shown on the landscape.Can anyone help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Personnally, I'll try to use

`-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` in your viewcontroller and redraw the scrollview depending on `toInterfaceOrientation`

Comment: Thanks, But I still can't show the same 12 imageViews as I mentioned before. Each time i rotate the device it will reset the scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want same display in portrait and landscape mode then you'll have live auto-resizing.

**For Enabling AutoResizing :**

1. goto your xib (if you declare each
   sub view in nib file) select all
   then LAYOUT>AUTO RESIZING
2. If you have declared sub views programmatically then you'll have to enable auto-resizing for each sub view item.

Then use orientation methods like

-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration